# What's the difference between grande and grosso?

Tags: difference, adjectives

I understand that both words mean big but when should one be used vs the other?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: It seems that you are generating different accounts and you are using the "Your Answer" form in an inappropriate way (this is intended only to give an answer to the question). Please, try to avoid that. Notice that you can always add a comment under your own post (once you have enough reputation, you will be able to  [comment everywhere](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)) and if you want to contact the user who has post the answer, you can write @AmbaRaba in your comment.

Comment: I'm an Italian-American (my great-grandparents emigrated way back when) whose last name is Grosso... and it makes me kinda sad 

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria Don't be, it is a fairly common last name in Italy. Even *Grasso* (*fat*!) is quite common...

Answer (score 5):

Both words mean large or great, both figuratively and physically, but they're used in slightly different contexts.

## When Talking About Items

*Grande* is often used when identifying a specific item against smaller ones. *Apri il libro grande* (not the small one).
*Grosso* is almost never used this way. (While "più grosso" might: *Passami il libro più grosso*)

*Grande* is often used to signify large, while *grosso* means big. *Un libro grande* has a large format, *un libro grosso* is bulky, with many pages.

When used before the noun, *grande* might also mean great, based on context. *Un grande libro* might be a large book or a really good one. Often both, if making a pun.

Effectively, an item can be *grande e grosso* if it is both large and bulky.

## When Talking About People

All that has been said for items still applies, with some variations.

*Grande* before the name most often signifies great.

*Grande* can also mean adult: *Una persona grande* = an adult. *Il fratello grande* = the older/oldest brother. *Filippo è grande, ormai* = Philip has grown up already.

*Grande* can be about physical height. *Guarda che grande è quel tizio* = look at how big that guy is.

*Grosso* is more about width.

Indeed, a guy can be *grande e grosso*, meaning tall and wide.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly noted, both *grande* and *grosso* can be translated as *big*.
However, although often interchangeable, on a figurative level their meaning can differ quite a bit.

Take for instance the following sentence: *there was a big boulder blocking the road*.
You could translate it as *c'era un **grosso** masso che bloccava la strada* or as *c'era un **grande** masso che bloccava la strada*. They are both perfectly acceptable.

On the other hand, there is a huge difference between saying *era un **grosso** uomo* and *era un **grande** uomo*. The first sentence would translate as *he was a **big** man*, where *big* denotes his being robust, corpulent, fat or even muscular. While the second sentence would translate as *he was a **great** man*, where *great* denotes his qualities as a person.

I believe this thread on Wordreference might help you get a better undestanding of the difference between these two words: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/grande-vs-grosso.615354/?hl=it

Comment: And do one of the words mean fat as well?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: @Beka yes, **grosso** can also mean *fat*, but it is not as derogative as *grasso*

Comment: Oh okay, so to summarize: big objects: grande or grosso,
big people (in size): grosso (polite/making observations) grasso (impolite/rude),
people with big/good characters: grande. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, that's correct but also a bit simplistic. Keep in mind that **grande** can basically apply to anything related to greatness on a figurative level. For instance you can talk about a *grande impresa* (a great endeavour) or a *grande sconfitta* (a great defeat) or again a *grande vittoria* (a great victory)...

Comment: @Beka, that would be a first, quite crude approximation. Just think that even the same adjective can get different nuances whether it appears before or after the noun it refers to. A _grande uomo_ (often _grand'uomo_) is indeed an illustrious man, while a _uomo grande_ is more a (physically) big man.

Comment: @Beka. And I wouldn't that saying _grosso_ of a man is polite: just slightly less impolite than _grasso_.